# Adding Custom Messages to JUnit4 Style Exception Tests

Tags: java, exception, junit, message

I have the following test:

```
@Test(expected=ArithmeticException.class) 
   public void divideByZero() {
   int n = 2 / 1;
}
```

as seen [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-junit4.html).

I would like to add a message that will print if this test fails.

For instance if I was doing an Assertion test, I would do the following to add a message:

```
@Test public void assertFail(){
    Assert.fail("This is the error message I want printed.");
    Assert.assertEquals(true, false);
}
```

The second example should print out "This is the error message I want printed.".  How do I set the first example message text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can easily, but [this](http://softwaredevscott.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!1A9E939F7373F3B7!524.entry) guy seems to have partially worked his way around it.

Comment: This answer may have been helpful but the link is now broken.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe `@Rule` annotation should help. Into your unit test class add sth like this:

```
import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.rules.MethodRule;
import org.junit.runners.model.Statement;
import org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod;
import org.junit.internal.runners.model.MultipleFailureException;
...
@Rule
public MethodRule failureHandler = new MethodRule()
{
    @Override
    public Statement apply(final Statement base, FrameworkMethod method, Object target)
    {
        return new Statement()
        {
            @Override
            public void evaluate() throws Throwable
            {
                List<Throwable> listErrors = new ArrayList<Throwable>();
                try
                {
                    // Let's execute whatever test runner likes to do
                    base.evaluate();
                }
                catch (Throwable testException)
                {
                    // Your test has failed. Store the test case exception
                    listErrors.add(testException);                        
                    // Now do whatever you need, like adding your message,
                    // capture a screenshot, etc.,
                    // but make sure no exception gets out of there -
                    // catch it and add to listErrors
                }
                if (listErrors.isEmpty())
                {
                    return;
                }
                if (listErrors.size() == 1)
                {
                    throw listErrors.get(0);
                }
                throw new MultipleFailureException(listErrors);
            }
        };
    }
};
```

Instead of collecting all the exceptions in `listErrors` you may consider wrapping `testException` with your exception with additional message and just throwing it.

Comment: Working on proving that this is a solution.  Thanks.

Comment: @KevinO I did something similar with rules once (a screen shot after failed test). If you're interested, I can provide my solution. However, I'm not sure how to handle exceptions. Hence, I'd be pleased if you share your solution.

Comment: I was unsuccessful at adding a junit failure message using ExpectedException.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend instead naming the test to make it obvious what the test is testing, so when some of your tests fail, they tell you what the problem is. Here's an example using the `ExpectedException` rule:

```
@RunWith(JUnit4.class)
public class CalculatorTest {
  @Rule
  public ExpectedException exception = ExpectedException.none();

  @Test
  public void divisionByZeroShouldThrowArithmeticException() {
    Calculator calculator = new Calculator();

    exception.expect(ArithmeticException.class);
    calculator.divide(10, 0);
  }
}
```

For details on `ExpectedException`, see [this article](http://www.infoq.com/news/2009/07/junit-4.7-rules) and [the ExpectedException JavaDoc](http://kentbeck.github.com/junit/javadoc/latest/org/junit/rules/ExpectedException.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to use [catch-exception](http://code.google.com/p/catch-exception/) instead of JUnit's built-in exception handling mechanisms, then your problem can be easily solved:

```
catchException(myObj).doSomethingExceptional();
assertTrue("This is the error message I want printed.",
           caughtException() instanceof ArithmeticException);
```